# firebase functions responding times by times

Tags: node.js, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

Much of the time the function return Null But  it's work sometimes cant figure out if it's the network
or a problem with firebase.

```
//add user via the admin sdk
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
   return admin
    .auth()
    .createUser({
      displayName: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      phoneNumber: data.phone,
      photoURL: data.imageLink,
    })
    .then(userRecord => {
      // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
      return {users: userRecord};
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return error;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try using async/await

```
//add user via the admin sdk
exports.addUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const user = await admin.auth().createUser({
      displayName: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      phoneNumber: data.phone,
      photoURL: data.imageLink,
    })
    console.log(user)
    return { users: user }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return error
  }
})
```

Comment: it's give me the same result reponding sometimes

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: i am calling  it with httpsCallabble.  I found out that it's  a problem with phone value